# How can I programmatically align an image to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to place an image horizontally centered at the very bottom of the screen (regardless of if it's the simulator, or an iPhone4, iPhone5, etc).  Basically I should just need to set its y to screen_height - image_height.

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-image.png"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width / 2, img.size.height / 2);

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);

    CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = screenSize.height - img.size.height;
    imgView.frame = frame;

    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

What am I doing wrong?  0,0 is the top left of the screen, so I don't understand why screen_height - image_height is wrong here... ?

Comment: Is your `self.view` covering the whole screen? Values in `frame` are relative to *superview*, not screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you calculate those position metrics in `-viewWillAppear` when the frame of the view controller's view is properly calculated. In `-viewDidLoad` the frame corresponds to the metrics loaded from the NIB and if your XIB is configured for 3,5" display the view will be higher on 4" displays (iPhone 5)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the screen height, use the superview view height:

```
self.view.frame.size.height
```

As the subview is placed in terms of its superview frame, not the frame of the screen.

You do also have a logical error, because you're setting the image view frame height to `img.size.height / 2` and then later using the `img.size.height` to set the y coordinate.

Comment: Hmmm..  It seems that the view thinks it's destined to be on an iphone4.  It positions the image perfectly in the simulator, but on my iphone5, the image is about 200px higher than it should be.

Comment: That's a different issue and relates to auto-resizing. If self.view is in a view controller and at the top level then the view controller should do it for you. If it isn't then you should set its frame to the bounds of the view your going to add it to before making it a subview. And set the autoresizingMask to flexi width and height.

Comment: I'd just like to note that it might be more readable to use CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) than accessing the height through the struct. From the same family there are also CGRectGetWidth(), CGRectGet(Min|Max)(X|Y)() which are also useful.

Answer (score 1):

Align the subview at the bottom of the screen and then use an autoresizing mask to make sure the bottom margin stays constant at 0. This will keep the subview aligned at the bottom of its superview even if the superview's frame changes.

e.g.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-image.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - img.size.height;
imgView.frame = frame;
imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to force it to the bottom of the screen:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
CGRect viewFrameOnScreen = [[view superview] convertRect:view.frame toView:nil];
viewFrameOnScreen.origin.y = screenBounds.size.height - viewFrameOnScreen.size.height;
view.frame = [[view superview] convertRect:viewFrameOnScreen fromView:nil];
```

But I doubt you want to unconditionally force it to the bottom of the screen, even if there is a tab bar or something there. Except in unusual circumstances, views shouldn't venture outside the bounds of their parent view. If you just want it at the bottom of the parent view, then

```
view.frame.origin.y = [view superview].bounds.size.height - view.frame.size.height;
```